# AspectJ with JSF1.2 

Tags: netbeans-6.9, jsf-1.2

I am using **JSF1.2** framework. **I didnt Integrate my application with Spring**.I want to perform profiling on method invocations. my application file is **EAR (EJB + WAR )**. i can get the session beans methods execution time with the help of interceptor but for WAR module i was suggested to use AspectJ in this blog. so i have written some code. is there any thing i need to do like **configuration details**. I added the required jar file of **AspectJ** is **JSF support AspectJ** with any configuration? my code is:

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
@Aspect
public class AopInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor{

public AopInterceptor() {
}

@Pointcut("execution (* *.*(..))")
public void profile(){}

@Around("profile()")
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("test start");
    Object obj=mi.proceed();
    System.out.println("test end");
    return obj;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please do not put `[closed]` in your question titles.  Thanks.

Comment: I have created a target in WAR build.xml file and I added the AspectJ jar files. Now I am getting all the invoked methods. here is the targer code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a target in WAR build.xml file and I added the AspectJ jar files. Now I am getting all the invoked methods. here is the targer code:

```
 <taskdef  classpath="C:/Users/s.kosna/Downloads/aspectj-1.6.11/lib/aspectjtools.jar"
 resource="org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties"/>
<target name="aspectj">
<echo level="info">--- aspectj (start) ---</echo>
<condition property="targetos" value="windows" else="unix">
    <os family="windows"/>
</condition>
<pathconvert targetos="${targetos}" property="javac.convertedClasspath" >
    <path path="${javac.classpath}" />
</pathconvert>
<iajc source="1.6" target="1.6" showweaveinfo="true" verbose="true" destdir="${build.classes.dir}"  >
    <inpath>
        <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    </inpath>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${javac.convertedClasspath}" />
    </classpath>
</iajc>
<echo level="info">LORDDOSKIAS BRUTAL TEST ---</echo>
</target>

<target name="-post-compile" depends="aspectj"></target>
```

put the above code in one package and add the above ant script in you war build.xml thats it it will work